# Nan value return in sum by use reduce in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I tried to create 2 function in same name one that don't  given a starting point and other
but i have problem that  the result give nan in function with no start point

```js
function sum(array,start){
  return array.reduce((result, item)  => result + item,start);
}
console.log(sum([1,8],8))

function sum(array){
  return array.reduce((result, item)  => result + item);
}

console.log(sum([1,8]))
```

Comment: Both examples seem to work just fine. Maybe the actual input data is the problem? Something like `[undefined, 8]` would indeed produce `NaN`.

Comment: both working on Google Chrome console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't really support function overloading.  But functionally, it's the same thing in this case to just use start if it exists, otherwise use 0:

```js
function sum(array,start)
{
  return array.reduce((result, item)  => result + item, start || 0);

}
 
console.log(sum([1,8],8))
console.log(sum([1,8]))
```

Comment: I like to use default values instead `function sum(array, start = 0) { ... `

Comment: Thank you so so much